# Trying to require password on django allauth social login with google workspace

Tags: django, google-oauth, google-workspace, django-allauth

The basic question is how to go about requiring a user to put in their password when using google SSO.  We have a few users who use the same device and don't want them to all be able to log in as each other.  If I could require a password after a unit of time that would be okay, but I think I have set in workspace to require login after 12 hours already.

Otherwise logging in with google works fine.  It's just requiring some kind of re-authentication periodically that we need.

Here is the basic setup on django

`SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = { 'google': { 'SCOPE': [ 'profile', 'email', ], 'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'access_type': 'online', } } }`

Have tried updating the login link to use action-reauthenticate

`{% provider_login_url 'google' action="reauthenticate" %}`

This forces the user to select their account but doesn't require a password.

Comment: I don't think you can force google to re-authenticate a user.  This is something that would be controlled by the account session policy in their Google Workspace. As far as Google is concerned, the user is authenticated.